# Convert double to minutes and seconds to work out walking/running pace

Tags: java, android-studio, calculator

I am working out the pace of a walk/run using my chronometer to get the elapsed seconds, and a distance calculator for distance and using the formulae pace = time/distance. Using the below code it converts the pace per minute into 2 decimal places up to .99 each minute. This is working fine but how can I convert this so it's in minutes and seconds. Thanks

```
public void calPace(){

double pace = 0;
       
paceTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.paceTextView);
      
if(chronometerOn) {
          
  int elapsedMillis = (int) (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase());
 
           double activityTimeMins = (double) elapsedMillis / 1000 / 60;
  
// only show after 0.1 mile to build pace up
  if(totalDistance>0.1){
             
        pace = activityTimeMins/totalDistance;

   paceTextView.setText("Pace : "+String.format("%.2f", pace)+" / mile");
      
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
Duration
.between(
    start , 
    Instant.now()
)
.dividedBy( laps )
.toMinutes() // Renders minutes-per-lap.
// and .toSecondsPart() (or .toSeconds()%60 in Java 8 & early Android)
```

## *java.time*

Do not roll-your-own date-time math. We have classes for that.

Capture the current moment as seen in UTC, with a resolution up to nanoseconds, but likely captured live in either milliseconds or microseconds.

```
Instant start = Instant.now() ;
```

Capture the moment again, at the end.

```
Instant end = Instant.now() ;
```

Calculate elapsed time.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( start , end ) ;
```

Interrogate the duration for its parts:

- In Java 9+, use the `toMinutes` method for total minutes, and `toSecondsPart` method for seconds: [`Duration::toMinutes`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toMinutes()) & [`Duration::toSecondsPart`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toSecondsPart()).
- In Java 8 and early Android, we must do the math ourselves for the seconds by using [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation): `Duration::toMinutes` and `Duration.toSeconds() % 60`.

### `Duration.dividedBy`

For your division (`pace = activityTimeMins/totalDistance`) we can use [`Duration.dividedBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#dividedBy(long)) to do the math.

Take example the turtle race where the winner finished the 3 inch distance in 90 seconds. How many seconds per inch?

```
Duration timePerInch = Duration.ofSeconds( 90 ).dividedBy( 3L ) ;
```

> PT30S

#### ISO 8601

The output shown there is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. The `P` marks the beginning. The `T` separates the years-month-days from the hours-minutes-seconds. So `PT30S` is a half minute.

- Always use ISO 8601 formats when exchanging date-time values as text.
- The formats may or may not be suitable for presentation to your users.

### Full example

Pull that all together.

```
Instant start = Instant.now() ;
…
Instant end = Instant.now() ;
Duration elapsed = Duration.between( start , end ) ;
int distance = … some number of laps, meters, miles, whatever.
Duration timePerDistanceUnit = elapsed.dividedBy( distance ) ; 
String message = 
    "Pace : " + 
    timePerDistanceUnit.toMinutes() + "m" +
    timePerDistanceUnit.toSecondsPart() + "s" +
    " per mile"
;
```

If your distance (our divisor here) is fractional rather than an integer, you'll need to do a bit of the math yourself.

```java
Duration.ofNanos(
    Double
    .valueOf( 
        elapsed.toNanos() / 1.5   // For 1.5 miles as example distance.
    )  
    .longValue()  
);
```

All together again.

```
Instant start = Instant.now() ;
…
Instant end = Instant.now() ;
Duration elapsed = Duration.between( start , end ) ;
double distance = … some number of laps, meters, miles, whatever.
Duration timePerDistanceUnit = 
    Duration.ofNanos(
        Double.valueOf( elapsed.toNanos() / distance ).longValue()
    )
; 
String message = 
    "Pace : " + 
    timePerDistanceUnit.toMinutes() + "m" +
    timePerDistanceUnit.toSecondsPart() + "s" +
    " per mile"
;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]